# How can I fetch data in my client component without exposing my API key to the client?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to fetch data, and then use pagination to pass a number back to the api URL and fetch more data by changing the value of `page`.

I am fetching data in my server component like this:

```
// fetchData.tsx
export const fetch_data = async (page: number) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api/data?key=${process.env.API_KEY}&page=${page}`);

  const res = await response.json();
  return res.results;
};
```

```
// page.tsx
export interface Card {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await fetch_data(1);

  return (
    <main>
        // can pass data props into ClientComponent
        <ClientComponent />
    </main>
  );
}
```

```
// ClientComponent.tsx
const data = await fetch_data(1);
// fetch does not work here because API_KEY is not available to the client.
...
return (
    {data.slice(0, 20).map((data: Card ) => (
      <Cards key={data.id} data={data} />
    ))}
    // MUI Pagination.
    <Pagination count={10} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the outcome I wanted by following [this article](https://xerosource.com/integrating-with-external-apis-in-nextjs/#how-to-integrate-with-external-ap-is-in-next-js). First move `fetchData` to `pages/api` in my root directory.  It looks like this now:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import axios from "axios";

export default async function fetchData(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  const { page } = req.query;
  const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api/data/items?key=${API_KEY}&page=${page}`,
    );
    const data = response.data;

    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching data" });
  }
}
```

Then, I made a new Component called, `ClientComponent`:

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";
import Cards from "./Cards";
import axios from "axios";

export interface CardType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export default async function ClientComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData(page: number) {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/fetchData?page=${page}`);
    const data = await response.data;
    setData(data.results);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(1);
  }, []);

  const onPageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>, value: number) => {
    fetchData(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="mt-5 flex flex-wrap justify-center ">
      <Pagination
        count={10}
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
        onChange={onPageChange}
      />
      <div className="mt-5 flex flex-wrap justify-center px-36 py-3">
        {data.map((data: CardType) => (
          <Cards key={data.id} data={data} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Pagination
        count={10}
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
        onChange={onPageChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally, my Home page now look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ClientComponentfrom "./components/ClientComponent";

export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        <ClientComponent/>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```